# OpenGL ES performance of different blending modes

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to apply full-screen photographic-like vignette effect over rendered scene. Obviously, I have to use blending to achieve this. I would like to choose the fastest possible blending mode because it will be applied to all screen space.

Do some blending modes in OpenGL ES work faster than another? Or does any blending mode work at the same fill-rate? So far I haven't found any resources on Internet saying that certain blending modes are slower or faster than another ones, so I decided to ask this question on SO.

This is for Android app, so I understand that of course this behavior can depend on GPU vendor, but maybe there are some common considerations for faster blending?

Comment: It's not that obvious to me. Depending on the fill rate (100% coverage, but perhaps not much more than 400%?) I'd also consider putting the vignetting effect directly on each fragment shader (via gl_FragCoord telling the pixel position on the screen).

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Yes I was thinking about this option too. Unfortunately, it is not applicable because there are some objects with blending and overdraw over each other (they are quite small so overdraw penalty is unnoticeable). If vignetting is applied to these objects in fragment shader it will be applied twice which is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one single slow part of blending is reading pixels from the backbuffer(doesn't matter alpha only or rgb or both). So as long as it's 'real' blending using `dst` color/alpha(i.e. not using a degenerate blend func like `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)`or `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE)` or similar) - there's no performance difference.

Comment: While @TraxNet's answer is also useful, it is not applicable in my case. Your answer provides simple and clean explanation of OpenGL blending behavior, thank you. I'm fully satisfied with your answer.

Comment: Yeah mine is almost duplicate of this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which blending option you choose, it is going to slow down the fragment shader as it needs to read back the pixel values from the target framebuffer. You can save some cycles by splitting your effect into some quads that are setup around the screen borders and leaving the central part of the framebuffer without overlaying quads. You can also do some more tricky approaches to use the early fragment discard employed by some tile based mobile GPUs like the Mali ones, but maybe is just not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for proposing early culling, it really can be useful in many cases, but I need to apply tint with gradients over the whole scene.

Answer (score 0):

To be short, no there is probably not a measurably worse blendmode (as long as you are doing "real" blending).

Blending can either be implemented by having a fixed function blend stage, or by adding a short tail to the shader program that will do the actual blending. Another solution is that fixed-function is used for most of the common blend modes, while a shader takes over if there is an uncommon blend mode. If you hit the shader one, your performance might take a hit.

Knowing what is good or bad would be very HW specific - and might not even be measurable due to the biggest cost is that you need to read and combine two buffers, not the relatively minor extra shading cost.